# Tortoise SVN reports files as "missing" or "deleted" although they are present on disk

Tags: tortoisesvn

When I open the commit dialog in tortoise svn, I can see that a lot of files are either *missing* or *deleted*, but I have them on disk.

What is the difference between missing and deleted?

How are they either missing or deleted if I have them?

(svn status does not report those files)

Comment: `missing` = file exists in repository but not in your working copy; `deleted` = file has been deleted in your working copy and should be deleted in the repository

Comment: @splash - it can|have to be answer

Comment: But I have them in my working copy.

Comment: Any news on this? I am stuck here as well

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. **missing**: means the file is actually missing in your working copy. This happens if you delete the file without using the svn command. You can restore the missing file by updating the working copy or using the revert command.
2. **deleted**: the file is deleted in svn, i.e. it is marked for deletion on the next commit. This status is shown even if the file itself is still in your working copy. If it's still in the working copy, it will be removed on the next commit. And the next commit will also remove the file from the repository.

Comment: I have chosen to "revert" all those files, the status stays the same.

Answer (score 4):

- **missing** = file exists in the repository but not in your working copy
- **deleted** = file has been deleted in your working copy and is about to be deleted in the repository

Comment: @AndersLindén Maybe your working copy is corrupted. Try a clean up or make a fresh checkout and sync your changes with the corrupted working copy.

Comment: It is not corrupted according to svn.exe?

Comment: Well I have an entire folder and its contents which neither exists in the repo nor in the working copy marked as missing